# How to return the remaining elements of a list after the last match?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Below is my input**

```
x = ['P' 'AE2' 'A' 'AE1' 'B' 'C']
```

My function is to return the **last** value within `x` that contains `0`, `1`, or `2` at the end of the value

i.e. `'AE2'` or `'AE1'`

and then any remaining values

**Desired Output**

```
y = ['AE1' 'B' 'C']
```

The values of `x` can vary thus the values of `y` will vary as well. I'm struggling on how to create a function for this problem.

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Creating the loop statement. I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Not exactly as I'm not returning all of  'X' in reverse. Only a portion of x that meets the criteria that I stated in my question.

Comment: Maybe this title would work better then? _How to return the remaining elements of a list after the last match?_

Comment: Please read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
reversed()
```

It should work.

You can access the index this way:

```
for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(a))):
    print i, e
```

prints

```
2 baz
1 bar
0 foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop, Thats the fun of python.
You can access list items easily

`li[:]` - This access the item 0 - nth.

`li[x:]` - Accesses x place till end. (x position could be 2,3 or any)

`li[::-1]` - Reverses the list.

> You can assign the manipulated list to a new list.

`new_list = li[0:3]` (It will store list item 0 - 3 index in the `new_list`)

Dig more about list manipulation in python, you would know more.

Comment: I guess you meant ```li[::-1]``` instead of ```li[-1::]```

Answer (score 0):

If you're a beginner, it might be good to try keep it as simple as possible. Divide the problem into three sections:

1. Find the index of the last element that match our condition.
2. Confirm that such an element actually exist!
3. Print the elements.

First section suggests that you have to loop through the list and check against all elements. Since you also need the index, as well as the element, it seems like you need to use a for loop with `enumerate`. What this do is to return the index of the element and the element itself. This is common to do in Python.

Next you need to check if the element ends with what you want. Luckily, Python's strings has a method called `endswith` that returns `True` if a string ends with any of the values passed to it.

Lastly, you just need to print from the index you've found and onward! Here's a more concrete example:

```
x = ['P', 'AE2', 'A', 'AE1', 'B', 'C']
matches = ('0', '1', '2')

# Gets the index of the last element that ends with 0, 1 or 2. We start off by going through each element one by one,
# and if the element match our condition, we save the element's index (the variable i). If we later find another element
# in the list we just override the current index.
index = -1
for i, element in enumerate(x):
    if element.endswith(matches):
        index = i

# If index still is -1, that means no elements matched our condition.
if index == -1:
    print('We did not find any element that ended in 0, 1 or 2!')
else:
    # Print all contents of x from index to the end.
    print(x[index:])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What said does make sense but not in the context of my problem. As stated the values of x can vary, therefore I simply can't just state the index where the match is found.

Comment: @alex114323 You aren't stating the index where the match is. You're iterating through the list and searching for the index where the match is. The `-1` is just a placeholder for _"No matches were found."_ If you try the snippet with different lists you'll notice you'll get a different index.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move backwards:

```
x= ['P', 'AE2', 'A', 'AE1', 'B', 'C']
for index in range(len(x)-1,-1,-1):
    if x[index][-1] in "012":
       print(x[index:])
       break   

['AE1', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` to do this in O(n)

```
from itertools import accumulate
x = ['P', 'AE2', 'A', 'AE1', 'B', 'C']
list(accumulate(x, lambda p,n: [n] if n[-1] in '012' else list(p)+[n]))[-1]
['AE1', 'B', 'C']
```